# "type does not exist in the namespace" error even though I added a project reference

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I have a Visual Studio Mac solution solution with 2 projects - a NUnit test project and a .net standard library.  I am getting compile-time errors in my test project referencing members from the .net standard library project.  I've added a project reference to the library project from my test project.

The library project compiles without errors and the library classes show up in the dot autocomplete when I type in the test project - it only seems to throw an error at compile-time on the test project.

Am I misunderstanding what a .net standard library project is?  I'm a bit confused about compatibility with target frameworks - the NUnit project is targeting .net framework 4.6.1 and the library is targeting .netStandard 1.4

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace MyLibNameSpace.Test
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class Tickets
    {
        [Test()]
        public async void ShouldGetTickets()
        {
            //error here below at compile time
            MyLibNameSpace.FreshDeskService svc = new MyLibNameSpace.FreshDeskService(); 
            var tickets = await svc.GetTicketsAsync();
            Assert.GreaterOrEqual(tickets.Count, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On Mac, your NUnit project is powered by Mono, which requires you to add necessary NETStandard.Library package reference.

Comment: " I am getting compile-time errors" - what *exactly* are the errors? What does the project look like? How are you building?

Comment: The error is "type does not exist in the namespace" at the commented line.  It's 2 projects in one solution.  One library project and one Test(NUnit) test project.  Test project has one test file as shown above, library file is a vanilla project with one poco class and a simple FreshDesk class.  Seems to be an issue with the target frameworks.